# Opening multiple queries in SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server

In a program I am working on I've used this code to start a session of SQL Server Management Studio and have it open a query in one tab:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\tracing\Ssms.lnk",@"\\MyServer\shared\MyQuery.sql");
```

I have another query that I wish to open in the SAME instance of SQL Server in DIFFERENT tab. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed any file registrations on the client, then this should work:

```
Process.Start(@"\MyServer\shared\MyQuery.sql");
```